# Error writing dataframe to SQL database table using dbWriteTable in R

Tags: sql, r, odbc, dbi

I'm attempting to create a new table in a SQL database from a series of dataframes that I've made available to the global environment (dataframes created via a function in R).

I'm able to connect to the server:

```
#libraries
library(odbc)
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)

#set up a connection to the database
staging_database <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "staging_db") 

#Write dataframe to table in database (table does not exist yet in SQL!)
dbWriteTable(staging_database , 'test_database', `demographics_dataframe`, row.names = FALSE)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: <SQL> 'CREATE TABLE "test_database" (


 "field1" varchar(255),
  "field2" BIT,
  "field3" BIT,
  "field4" varchar(255),
  "field5" varchar(255),
  "field6" varchar(255),
  "field7" varchar(255),
  "field8" INT,
  "field9" INT,
```

Very unhelpful error here - is there something I'm missing?  I've followed the documentation for dbWritetable.  Something I'm noticing, that I believe may be a part of the problem, is that I can't view any existing tables within "staging_db".

`dbListTables(staging_database)` reveals a bunch of metadata, but no actual tables that exist (I can verify they exist by logging into Microsoft SQL Server).

Comment: assuming your `demographics_dataframe` is the data frame you want to write to your database, it shouldn't have the backward ticks?

Comment: that's how it autocompletes the dataframe in R.  Without those quotes, it gives me an unexpected symbol error.

Comment: that's odd, can't really say much without info on the db connection other than probably worth checking your write access for the db and if `demographics_dataframe` is a data.frame or can be coerced to be one?

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same error. In my case, there was no problem with special characters or unexpected symbols anywhere in the table, since I was able to write the table “piece by piece” each time writing only a subset of columns.

I am guessing it has something to do with the number of columns to be written. In a single go, I was able to write up to 173 columns.

Rather than think that this is the limit I would say there is an internal limit for the length of the “CREATE TABLE” string hidden somewhere along the way.

Workaround that worked for me was to split the table into 2 sets of columns with the ID in both of them and joining them later.

#### Edit

So the truth was for me that 2 columns had the same name. The error indeed comes from the "CREATE TABLE" string - one cannot create table with duplicated column names.

Even a year after asking the question, I hope this can help someone dealing with the same problem ;)